# How to delete polygons/edges/vertices at once, without selecting the corresponding item in the menu on the X key?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface, add-on, edit-mode

I've read in other threads that Blender needs to know exactly what I want to remove in the selection. But it's not obvious to me why Blender can't remove those values that I already use for selection - selection of vertices/edges/polygons.
Perhaps if Blender can't do that, are there any plugins or addons that add such a feature? I would appreciate any of your help or advice.

[image: Delete menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to delete vertices (which does delete everything you selected) you could assign a shortcut here:

[image]

Just right click on that menu entry, assign a shortcut you want and select what you wanna delete, then press your shortcut.

And of course you can assign to other menu entries shortcuts as well, if you wanna delete something else and i might have misunderstood you.

Comment: This is the closest solution so far. I will be able to make three different shortcuts for three delete commands. It's not as convenient as if blender could figure out what to remove on its own, but it's still better than choosing something from the menu each time.
Thanks for the advice!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is some Blenderish logic to it: if the delete operation followed the selection mode, there would still be distinctions unresolved: if you're in Face selection, do you want to delete faces *and* their edges (which is not the same as deleting edges, and all their dependent faces), or leave their edges  intact? .. or, if deleting faces / edges, do you want to leave only the vertices behind?

It's also Blenderish, (whatever toolbars are provided,) that keyboard shortcuts are the way to fast modelling. Those are indicated by the underlined chatracters on the menu. So, for example, <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> will delete faces, leaving edges behind.

You might also want to look at the shipped add-on: '3D Viewport Pie Menus'  which  provides swipe-gestures, too. (Annoyingly, the keyboard shortcuts in those are slightly different)

Comment: In 99% of cases, if I need to delete several polygons, then I also need to delete their common edges. For another option, I can select Only Faces from the delete menu. This applies to all rarely used delete commands. Most often I need the top three items - deleting vertices, edges, faces.
Therefore, I wanted to optimize this process, because I want to skip the stage of selecting an item in the menu in the program itself, and do everything at once with 1 click on the keyboard or an additional mouse button.
I'll take the advice about shortcuts, thanks!

Comment: @solo_GRV.. I do see what you mean. That would be a sensible default.  Having said that..  IMO, Blender, on the whole, so far, is pretty good at being minimal, consistent and complete in its modelling interface. Personally, I much prefer it to hunting through forests of options in some other 3D applications.